# rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- test/unit/error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems, social-networking, ruby-1.9.3

I am trying to install insoshi in Rails 3.2.21 with ruby 1.9.3 every thing gone good but now I am stopped with an error when I try `$rake gems:install` it gives an error

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- test/unit/error
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:1
53:in `block in require'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:5
21:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:1
53:in `require'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/deprecation.rb:22
4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:1
53:in `block in require'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:5
21:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:1
53:in `require'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support.rb:37:in `<top (r
equired)>'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/misc.rake:11:in `<top (required
)>'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `load'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `block in <top (r
equired)>'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `each'
C:/Sites/insoshi/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `<top (required)>
'
C:/Sites/insoshi/Rakefile:10:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am totally new with rails. hope for help

Comment: Try with ``bundle install`` instead of ``rake gems:install``.

Comment: There is no Gemfile in insoshi